# Modeling of elections: ordinal response regression?

Tags: classification, elections

I am trying to model a series of $N$ elections, where I observe only wins and losses, and where there are no ties.

To be clear, my problem is defined as follows: the $i$th election has $n_i$ candidates (this is different for each election) and a single observed winner. $y_{i,j}$ is the 0/1 indicator for whether candidate $j$ won election $i$. There are $K$ different 'independent' variables (really observed features) about each candidate, call them $x_{i,j,k}$. Given the $x$ and $y$ data, I need to build a model to predict future elections, where, ideally, the output is probability of winning the election (and these should sum to 1). We can ignore the time-series components of elections for now.

Is this a known problem?  I am not sure what terms to search for, since this is not exactly a logistic regression (one candidate *always* wins).